# Physically move SSD in 2017 MacBook Air to 2018 MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd

I have a Macbook Air 2017 with 512GB SSD and I want to put the drive in a 2018 MacBook Pro that came with only 128GB.

What do I need to do this?

Comment: According to [everymac.com](https://everymac.com/systems/by_year/macs-released-in-2018.html), Apple did not make a 2018 MacBook Pro with only a 128 GB internal SSD.

Answer (score 2):

You can’t do this.

The 2018 MacBook Pro storage is soldered to the logic board and is very different from the proprietary M.2 interface of the 2013-2017 MacBook Air computers. This applies to both the 15-inch and 13-inch models.

You either have to get an MacBook Pro  with greater internal storage or you can remove the SSD from the 2017 and put it into an external enclosure; that’s if the 2017 MBA is otherwise useless.  If it still has life, then get an external drive for additional storage.